# How to change the company complete backend based on the current syntax?

Tags: completion, company-mode, comment

I would like to have natural language completion (`company-ispell` for e.g.) but only when editing comments.

How should the company back-end be swapped out when editing commensts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert below code into `~/.emacs` to enable `company-ispell` in comment,

```
(defun my-in-comment-p (pos)
  "Check whether the code at POS is comment by comparing font face."
  (let* ((fontfaces (get-text-property pos 'face)))
    (if (not (listp fontfaces))
        (setq fontfaces (list fontfaces)))
    (delq nil
          (mapcar #'(lambda (f)
                      ;; learn this trick from flyspell
                      (or (eq f 'font-lock-comment-face)
                          (eq f 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))
                  fontfaces))))

(eval-after-load 'company-ispell
  '(progn
     ;; use company-ispell in comment when coding
     (defadvice company-ispell-available (around company-ispell-available-hack activate)
       (cond
        ((and (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
              (or (not (company-in-string-or-comment)) ; respect advice in `company-in-string-or-comment'
                  (not (my-in-comment-p (point))))) ; auto-complete in comment only
         (setq ad-return-value nil))
        (t
         ad-do-it)))))
```

Comment: Notes: seems `setf` could be `setq`? Also `let*` can be `let`. Added alternate answer.

Comment: `setf` is still syntax correct though I admit it's kind of over-engineering in this case. `let*` is more powerful then `let` when multiple variable are initialized and there is dependency of initialization among the variables.

Comment: The function `(face-at-point nil t)` looks like it can replace the font accessing logic here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of @chen-bin's answer which uses a wrapper function instead of using advice (avoids interfering with other uses). It also generalizes the syntax checking to allow checking for other kinds of syntax.

```el
(defun company-complete-common-use-context ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((faces-found (face-at-point nil t))
        (faces-comment-list
         '(font-lock-comment-face
           font-lock-comment-delimiter-face
           font-lock-doc-face)))
    (cond
     ((seq-intersection faces-found faces-comment-list)
      (let ((company-backends (list 'company-ispell)))
        (company-complete-common)))
     (t
      (company-complete-common)))))
```

Then bind the key to `company-complete-common-use-context`.

Comment: This solution works for me if I am using something like <M-tab>, but is there any way of making it also work for completion on any key stroke?

Comment: The other answer here (chen bin's) uses advice which should work automatically without having to bind a key to a spesific function.